# Change the href of drupal breadcrumbs to custom link

Tags: php, drupal-7, breadcrumbs

I need to change the `href` attribute of `drupal7` breadcrumbs to custom URL's.

I am unable to find where it generates the links.

Comment: well, tried to search in files from where the breadcrumbs can be generated.. like menu.inc but no luck. i just need to find from where these breadcrumbs are being generated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great module, called Hansel, to do this job:

http://drupal.org/project/hansel

Description, how to set up Hansel is here:

http://www.knackforge.com/blog/sabareesh/breadcrumbs-hansel-module-1-introduction

http://www.knackforge.com/blog/sabareesh/breadcrumbs-hansel-module-2-steps-create-breadcrumbs-all-scenarios